# How can I embed a simple Grep type text file dictionary in my weebly site?

Tags: file, dictionary, search, text

I have a website that presents a text file dictionary under weebly.

https://indeo.weebly.com/dictionary.html

Instead of telling visitors to install a dictionary reader for the text file, I would like to have a simple dictionary search engine embedded that displays results in-page.

Comment: I solved this issue myself by downloading this elefen dictionary as html and javas. Afterward I changed it to my own invented language. This elefen is a very straightforward easy to change script: http://elefen.org/disionario/